# New row for printf "%s"

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

DISTRIBUTION_CENTERS=London
printf "%s" $DISTRIBUTION_CENTERS
```

When running the script London prints out before my username/hostname. I thought I get a new row with \n, "%s\n". \n works for integer although not for characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

DISTRIBUTION_CENTERS=London
printf "%s\n" $DISTRIBUTION_CENTERS
```

Or:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

DISTRIBUTION_CENTERS=London
echo $DISTRIBUTION_CENTERS
```

Comment: “%s” quotes from the book, that didn't work with \n. So I changed the quotes to ". I never seen “ ”, are they in american keyboards?

Comment: @user2062275 those are curly quotes and are syntactically incorrect you should always use straight quotes. No it has nothing to do with American keyboards, if it was code from a book then the publishes decision was to use them. Be careful when copy and pasting code.